# Photo Sharing Vs Storage

Tags: web, amazon-web-services, storage, web-hosting, file-sharing

There are lot of photo sharing applications out there, some are making money and some don't. Photo sharing takes lot of space, so I doubt where they host these! Rich services probably using Amazon or their own server, but the rest? Do they have access to any kind of free service? Or they have purchased terabytes from their web host?

Comment: Ads! Do you have any particular service in mind?

Comment: @SimonSvensson: I did not understand you, No I have no particular server in mind. I am just seeking for something like that, because Amazon is too much for my Non-Profit work.

Comment: Image hosting services serve ads. That's how they earn money. Your images drives traffic to them, and they serve ads when others view your images. Ads.

Answer (score 1):

AWS S3 is what you are generally referring to. The cost is mainly due to the reliability they give to the data they store. For photo-sharing, generally this much reliability is not required (compared with say a financial statement).

They also have other services like S3 RRS (Reduced redundancy), and Glacier. They are lot cheaper. Say those photos not accessed for a long time may be kept on Glacier (it will take time to retrieve, but cheap). RRS can be used for any transformed images (which can be re-constructed even if lost) - like thumbnails. So these good photo-sharing services, will do a lot of such complicated decisions on storage to manage cost.

You can read more on these types here : http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/

There is also a casestudy of SmugMug on AWS. I also listened to him once, where he was telling about using his own hard-disks initially to store, but later S3 costs came down and he moved on to AWS. Read the details here:
AWS Case Study: SmugMug's Cloud Migration : http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/smugmug/